# Is there an easy way to see that $\left(2 \tan^2x+2\right)^3 = 8\left(\tan^2x+1\right)^3$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, integration, trigonometry

I'm reading this explanation of integrals with quadratics and the author pulled this out of nowhere.  Is it obvious to everyone but me that this statement is true?

Comment: Yes.  $$(2\tan^2x + 2)^3 = (2(\tan^2x + 1))^3=2^3(\tan^2x + 1)^3=8(\tan^2x + 1)^3.$$

Comment: **Hint** $\rm\,\ (2\,y)^3 =\, 8\,y^3\ \, $

Comment: $(2a^2+2)^3=[2(a^2+1)]^3=2^3(a^2+1)^3$ This is true for any $a$, for $a=\tan x$ you get your equality.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since
$$2\tan^2 x + 2 = 2(\tan^2 x + 1),$$
we see that
$$(2\tan^2 x + 2)^3 = 2^3(\tan^2 x + 1)^3.$$

Comment: *facepalm.  It's so obvious. Thanks.